# How to parse URL with forward slash in userinfo part

Tags: ruby, uri, userinfo

I have a URL of this format:

```
https://clientjiberish:clientsecretjiberish@api.example.com/users?username=tralala
```

when I do:

```
url = 'https://clientjiberish:clientsecretjiberish@api.example.com/users?username=tralala'
uri = URI(url)
```

I get all that I need.

```
uri.host => "api.example.com"
uri.userinfo => "clientjiberish:clientsecretjiberish"
uri.path => '/users'
uri.scheme => 'https'
```

The problem rises when the userinfo part has a forward slash in it. I have no power to change the API that serves the API keys, so I need to figure out a way to extract the mentioned parts of the URI.

Here's an example on what you can test the URI:

```
url = 'https://clientjiberish:client/secretjiberish@api.example.com/users?username=tralala'
uri = URI(url)
```

The error:

> URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?)

I found out that you can create your own parser like this:

```
parser = URI::Parser.new(:RESERVED => ";/?:@&=+$,\\[\\]")
uri = parser.parse(url)
```

but I don't know enough about regex to make it work.

Comment: Can you not just escape forward slash in `client/secretjiberish` with `%2F`?.

Comment: @Rashmirathi
How can I access it? If I do something like:

escaped_url = URI.escape(url, '/') and then URI(url) I can't use any of the URI methods since they all return nil.

Comment: I mean only escape it in the part `clientjiberish:client/secretjiberish `, so url becomes `https://clientjiberish:client%2Fsecretjiberish@api.example.com/users?username=tralala`.

Comment: I receive a string ```'https://clientjiberish:clientsecretjiberish@api.example.com/users?username=tralala'```. How do I just escape that part of the string?

Answer (score 0):

```
url = 'https://clientjiberish:client/secretjiberish@api.example.com/users?username=tralala'
USER_INFO_REGEX = /\Ahttp[s]+:\/\/(.*)@.*\z/i
user_info = USER_INFO_REGEX.match(url)[1]
parsed_user_info = user_info.gsub(/\//, '%2F')
url = url.gsub(Regexp.new(user_info), parsed_user_info)
uri = URI(url)
```

`USER_INFO_REGEX` matches the string between `https://` and `@api.example.com...`. Just escape the user info string and replace it in the url.